# Python import from subdirectory, files in subdirectory can't see each other

Tags: python

I want to clean up my project and seperate stuff into sub dirs.
One of them contains auto-generated files lets say:

```
Sub: a.py and b.py
Root: master.py
```

master.py depends on a.py and a.py on b.py

Using (in master.py)

```
import sub.a as a
```

I can import a just fine, but a.py can't import b.py as the auto generated files will always use a simple (code in auto gen. a.py)

```
import b
```

instead of:

```
import sub.b as b
```

I can fix this by hand and it works, but isn't there way to tell python, to treat the whole sub dir as a module or something, so that the files in my sub dir see each other?

Comment: You'll likely have to add the path to `/sub` to `PATH` so that you can treat the subdirectory as a module. But I'm not sure if you'll want to have cross-dependencies between files *within* your module (danger of cyclic dependency...) - that's not the idea behind putting code together in a module if you ask me.

Comment: Well a.py and b.py are actually grpc files, automatically generated, so nothing I can do about. I'm not sure if it could cause cyclic dependencys here as root depends on a and a on b, so it's hierarchical(?), but as a can't see b it fails. path would be an option. I hoped there would be a more elegant way of doing this.